# Looping though mulitiple text files to data extraction in Python

Tags: python, database-design, data-manipulation

I've been learning Python on my own since October in order to extract data from about one million text files.  I've been trying to tackle this in small discreet chunks so that I don't get overwhelmed/lost in trying to get all the code I want in one go.

For my first chunk, I want to extract addresses from the text files.  So far, I've managed to get my code working one file at a time, but since I have over 1 million to go through I don't think that doing this manually will work.

For brevity's sake, I've only included the first part of my code since the rest is basically this but looking for different keywords.

```
######
#Importing/creating modules
######
import os
import re
regex = re.compile('\d+')
######
#Creating N/A text for non-existing entries
######
CV2 = """N/A
N/A
"""


######
#Opening Database file 
######
target = open('C:/project/database.csv', 'a')



####
#Opening the source documents
####
big_file = open('C:/project/0000068100-99-000018.txt', 'r')




####
#Looking for central key
####
for line in big_file:
    if 'CENTRAL INDEX KEY:' in line:
        key = regex.findall(line)


####
#Looking for Conforming Period
####
big_file = open('C:/project/0000068100-99-000018.txt', 'r') 
for line in big_file:
    if 'CONFORMED PERIOD OF REPORT:' in line:
        conform = regex.findall(line)


#####
#Looking for File Type
#####       
big_file = open('C:/project/0000068100-99-000018.txt', 'r') 
for line in big_file:
    if 'CONFORMED SUBMISSION TYPE:' in line:
        type_temp = re.split('\s+',line) 
        type1 = type_temp [3]
        type = type1.split()



#####
#Looking for company name
#####   
big_file = open(''C:/project/0000068100-99-000018.txt', 'r')    
for line in big_file:
    if 'COMPANY CONFORMED NAME:' in line:
        name_temp = re.split('\:+',line) 
        name1 = name_temp [1]
        name2 = name1.split()
        name3 = ' '.join(name2)
        name = re.split('\::+',name3) 





####
#Looking for Street and Mail Addresses
####

big_file = open('C:/project/0000068100-99-000018.txt', 'r')
f = open('C:/Users/Martin/Thesis/address1.txt', 'w+')
for line in big_file:
    if 'STREET 1:' in line:
        f.write(line)



f = open('C:/project/address1.txt', 'w+')
a = open('C:/project/address1a.txt', 'w+')
b = os.path.getsize('C:/project/address1.txt')
########
#If empty, return NA, if not clean unnesseary tabs and formmating from line 
########
if b == 0:
    a.write(CV2)        
else:
    for line in f:
        type_temp = re.split('\:+',line) 
        add_temp = type_temp[1]
        add_temp_temp = ''.join(add_temp)
        add = re.split('\t+',add_temp_temp)
        tempo = "".join(add)
        a.write(tempo)
        #print tempo


a = open('C:/project/address1a.txt', 'w+')
lines=a.readlines()
bus1 = lines[0]
bus2 = re.split('\n+',bus1)
bus3 = bus2 [0]
business1 = re.split('\::+',bus3)
########
#Preping for inclusion for the Database entry 
########
mail1 = lines[1]
mail2 = re.split('\n+',mail1)
mail3 = mail2 [0]
mailad1 = re.split('\::+',mail3)


#####
#Formatting data tags
#####
company_name_temp = "Company Name"
company_name = re.split('\::+',company_name_temp)
bus_street1_temp = "Business Street 1"
bus_street1 = re.split('\::+',bus_street1_temp)
mstreet1_temp = key + conform + type + mail_street1 + mailad1
mstreet1 = ','.join(mstreet1_temp)




######
#Prepping for database
######
name_temp1 = key + conform + type + company_name + name
co_name = ','.join(name_temp1)

bstreet1_temp = key + conform + type + bus_street1 + business1
bstreet1 = ','.join(bstreet1_temp)

mstreet1_temp = key + conform + type + mail_street1 + mailad1
mstreet1 = ','.join(mstreet1_temp)



######
#Writing to database
######
target.write(co_name)
target.write("\n")
target.write(bstreet1)
target.write("\n")
target.write(mstreet1)
target.write("\n")
```

I tried to open the file once at the top and call the variable multiple times, but it did not work, and I'm assuming that the for loop would look similar to this, but I have no idea on how to make it work.

```
for filename in os.listdir('C:/project'):
    bigfile = filename
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `open` returns `FileObjects` that actually stream, so you can't access it multiple times--really only once.  What you want to do here is something more like this:

```
for filename in os.listdir('C:\project'):
    bigfile = open(filename, 'r').read()
    # Now the file contents are saved within bigfile, and you can do as you please,
    #  accessing multiple times.
```

This is not recommended if your files are huge, since it will take a lot for Python to read in and save the whole file.  That is the exact reason `open` streams the file data, so you can access it as much at a time as you please instead of being forced to take the whole chunk at once.

By the way, you should look into the `csv` module.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, but I think I'm missing something here.  I tried implementing your suggestion (again starting small - just searching for the ID key), and I'm not getting anything under keys.    I tried just the code you you suggested just by itself and I get a an empty line when I try to print Bigfile or a list of file when I print filename.

Comment: Oops, forgot to re-open my files in each sub-block.  It's working now.